# get parent from nested array with multiple nested sub childs

Tags: javascript

I need a function that gets parent from the nested array with multiple nested sub child

```
    getAncestors(array, route) {
    if (typeof array !== "undefined") {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].route === route) {
          return array[i];
        }
        const a = this.getAncestors(array[i].children, route);
        if (a !== null) {
          return array[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Current Function return only first-level parent, I need all nested parent details.
like if we are on `/dashboard/orders/` it should `['dashboard Object', ['Orders Reports Object']]`

JSON :

```
{
   "route":"/dashboard",
   "name":"Dashboard",
   "icon":"pie_chart",
   "permissions_required":"admin",
   "children":[
      {
         "route":"/dashboard",
         "name":"Orders Reports",
         "icon":"dashboard",
         "children":[
            {
               "route":"/dashboard/orders/",
               "name":"Orders",
               "icon":"local_mall"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "route":"/dashboard/sales/channel-wise-sales",
         "name":"Channel wise Sales",
         "icon":"notes"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: so, you're passing the full array and a final route, and you want all the branches until you find your leaf. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function can do that for you, walking the tree until it finds the route.

```js
const tree = {
  "route": "/dashboard",
  "name": "Dashboard",
  "icon": "pie_chart",
  "permissions_required": "admin",
  "children": [{
      "route": "/dashboard",
      "name": "Orders Reports",
      "icon": "dashboard",
      "children": [{
        "route": "/dashboard/orders/",
        "name": "Orders",
        "icon": "local_mall"
      }]
    },
    {
      "route": "/dashboard/sales/channel-wise-sales",
      "name": "Channel wise Sales",
      "icon": "notes"
    }
  ]
};

function lookup(route, node) {
  if (node.children)
    for (let child of node.children) {
      if (child.route === route)
        return [node.name + " Object"]
      let find = lookup(route, child);
      if (find)
        return [node.name + " Object", find];
    }
}

console.log(lookup("/dashboard/orders/", tree));
```

The only quirk is that as the actual target ("Orders" in this case) should not appear in the result, the check happens before jumping into a child.

Answer (score 0):

> The following code returns the matching item and set a parent var

```
const nestedArray = {
       "route":"/dashboar",
       "name":"Dashboar",
       "icon":"pie_chart",
       "permissions_required":"admin",
       "children":[
          {
             "route":"/dashboar-child",
             "name":"Orders Reports",
             "icon":"dashboard",
             "children":[
                {
                   "route":"/dashboard/orders/",
                   "name":"Orders",
                   "icon":"local_mall"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "route":"/dashboard/sales/channel-wise-sales",
             "name":"Channel wise Sales",
             "icon":"notes"
          }
       ]
    };
    
    var childParent = null;
    
    const findItemNestedParent = (arr, route, nestingKey, parent= null) => {
    
        if(childParent) return childParent;
    
      return arr.reduce((a, item) => {
        if (a) {
            return a;
        }
        if (item.route === route) {
            childParent = {...parent};
          return item;
        }
        else if (item[nestingKey])
            return findItemNestedParent(item[nestingKey], route, nestingKey, {...item})
      }, null)
    }
    
    
    console.log("matching item", findItemNestedParent([{...nestedArray}], '/dashboard/orders/', 'children', null))
    console.log("matching item parent", childParent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  getAncestors(array, route) {
    if (array === undefined) return false;
    let matchedElement: any[] = [];
    array.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.route.replace(/\/$/, "") === route) {
        matchedElement = [element];
      } else {
        if (element.children) {
          const isExist: any[] = this.getAncestors(element.children, route);
          if (isExist.length) {
            matchedElement = [element].concat(isExist);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return matchedElement;
  }
```

This is how I resolve my issue.